# Swap an object in a Mongoose array with another object in the array of another document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Consider this schema:

```
    let userSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    books: [{
        owner: String,
        cover: String,
        title: String,
        link: String,
        requestsReceived: { requestingUser: String, bookOffered: String },
        requestsSent: { toUser: String, bookWanted: String },
        beingRequested: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        beingSent: { type: Boolean, default: false }
    }],
    ip: String
});
```

the books array contains objects which hold a variety of information. How can I take a certain book object from array of **document 1** and swap it with array of **document 2** preferably with the least amount of queries to the DB. (i.e. between two different user documents)

I know this is a bit difficult. Much appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by swap? do you want to move a book from doc1 to doc2?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean